# How to get all lines of JSON without knowing schema with JsonNode?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, jsonnode

Let's say I am expecting a simple JSON response from an API like so:

```
{
  "message": "Source: ",
  "incomingUrl": "https://10.1.1/api/echo",
  "incomingHeadersCount": 21,
  "apiVersion": "1.0"
}
```

I can use JsonNode to parse it and output the lines. This requires me to access it by specifying the key:

```
var parsedJson = JsonNode.Parse(apiResponse.Result);
Console.WriteLine(parsedJson["message"]);
```

I'd prefer to do something like this where I don't have to know any of the keys:

```
foreach (var item in parsedJson)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This should return, "Source: ", "https://10.1.1/api/echo", "21", "1.0". Is this possible with JsonNode?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use JsonNode?

This loops through all properties:

```
var data = JsonNode.Parse(apiResponse.Result).AsObject();
foreach(var item in data)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value);

}
```

One drawback with this approach is that you'll need to know what type the `value` is, since you'll need to call `.GetValue<T>()` on the value.
Assuming it's always a string, just call `.GetValue<string>()`.
If you just want to print the value you are fine though.

You could also deserialize directly to a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
var items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>(apiResponse.Result);

foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

If the values are of different types, [you could create a custom JsonConverter and deserialize to a Dictionary<string, object>](https://josef.codes/custom-dictionary-string-object-jsonconverter-for-system-text-json/).

Comment: I just tried the `JsonSerializer` approach. It fails to serialize it into a string. I'm guessing because "incomingHeadersCount" is an `int`? If that's how it is supposed to work, that is fine. I can work around it. Just want to make sure

Comment: Ah sorry thought that it was all string values...yeah an Int can't be stored in a Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: You could add a custom JsonConverter and deserialize to a Dictionary<string, object>
https://josef.codes/custom-dictionary-string-object-jsonconverter-for-system-text-json/

Answer (score -1):

the simpliest way is to use linq

```
List<JsonValue> data = JsonNode.Parse(apiResponse.Result).AsObject()
                               .AsEnumerable().Select(d => d.Value.AsValue())
                               .ToList();
```

and to display

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data));
```

output

```
Source: , https://10.1.1/api/echo, 21, 1.0
```

or to Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = JsonNode.Parse(apiResponse.Result).AsObject()
                                         .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, 
                                                       d => d.Value.ToString());
                               
 Console.WriteLine(dict["message"]); // "source: "
```